# How do I detect when a pdf's text was successfully extracted with PyPDF2.extractText?

Tags: python, string, pdf, pypdf

I'm using the PyPDF2 library to extract text from PDF files via its [`extractText`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.extractText) function, and for most PDFs, it works great!

However, some PDFs produce text that looks like this:

> \n!"#$%&'()"*+,"-."*.)/"0$-1"2)+3-$.45\n""!"#$%&'()*#'+),$!"#-.#*$-/$0.1+"*#+12$\n!"#"$!%"&#"%$'$()%*+,-$(%.($#"$(%"&#*%/%0!%\n$0"&$(%1(0,$2%3(%0"%0!%"&$%1(34+5"%36%1(0,$!7\n%%8%!"#$%&'($)%"\n%0!%#%*+,-$(%"&#"%0!%3*9)%40'0!0-9$%-)%/%#*4%0"!$967\n%%:%0!%"&$%3*9)%$'$*%\n1(0,$%*+,-$(7\n%%;3%099+!"(#"$%6+*4#,$*"#9%"&$3($,%36%#(0"&,$"052%<%90!"%-$93=%"&$%1(0,$%6#5"3(0>#"03*%\n36%*+,-$(!%-$"=$$*%/%#*4%:?7%@(0,$%*+,-$(!%#($%0*%\n6.'78"AB%,$#*!%,+9"019)7C\n%"/D%E$0"&$(%1(0,$%*3(%53,13!0"$7%\n%:D%9%%%%%%%/FD%:BG\n%HD%:%%%%%%%/?D%HB?\n%%FD%:B:\n%3(

According to [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.extractText), this be expected:

> This works well for some PDF files, but poorly for others, depending
>   on the generator used.

Unfortunately, the `extractText()` function doesn't raise any exceptions when it outputs text like the above.

So, my question is, is there a way to programmatically detect when the `extractText()` function returns gibberish?

Comment: There is a list of 236,000+ English words in `nltk.corpus.words.words()`. Split your text into words and check now many of them are in the NLTK corpus. If not too many or none - then your text is not really a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@DYZ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401342/how-do-i-detect-when-a-pdfs-text-was-successfully-extracted-with-pypdf2-extract/44417644#comment75802467_44401342), here's the solution.

`document_path` is assumed to the path to the `PDF` file you're opening. The rest should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from nltk.corpus import words

words = words.words()
document_file = PdfFileReader(open(document_path, 'rb'))
num_pages = document_file.getNumPages()
for page_num in range(0, num_pages):
    page = document_file.getPage(page_num)
    page_contents = page.extractText()
    if set(page_contents.lower().split()).intersection(words):
        # process page_contents
```